# Proving that there isn't a way to take the trace of a matrix with a linear transformation (or what conditions are necessary for this to be possible)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have the following system:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{22} \\
a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This would give me the columns vector that would take the trace of the matrix. Obviously if no there is no known relationship between the elements than the only guaranteed solution that exists is a contradictions because the first row implies $x=1$ while $y=z=0$ with similar results for the other equations.

The part I'm wondering about is how would I know when a relationship between the $a$'s means that there is a a possible solution?

The first equation can be written as $a_{11}(x-1) + a_{12}y + a_{13}z$ with similar results for the others... How would I identify the relationships that make it possible for the system of equations to hold?

Comment: For any invertible matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ there will be a solution $\left(x, y, z\right)$. The appearance of $a_{11}$ on the right hand side doesn't need to come from $x=1$ because $x$, $y$, and $z$, being dependent on the various elements of $\left(a_{ij}\right)$, will themselves contain information about them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_1,c_2,c_3$ be the columns of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$

The system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{22} \\
a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$

has a solution $\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z 
\end{bmatrix}$ $ \iff xc_1+yc_2+zc_3= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{22} \\
a_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \iff \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{22} \\
a_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \in span(c_1,c_2,c_3).$